# React composition with generic components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use component composition to design an autocomplete component whose interface will be like:

```
<Autocomplete.Root value={currentValue} onChange={handleChange}>
    <Autocomplete.Input />
    <Autocomplete.Dropdown>
        {options.map((option) => (
            <Autocomplete.Option value={option.value}>{option.label}</Autocomplete.Option>
        )}
    </Autocomplete.Dropdown>
</Autocomplete.Root>
```

These components need the type parameter `T` (the type of the value):

- `Autocomplete.Root`
- `Autocomplete.Input`
- `Autocomplete.Option`

Currently they all specify their own type parameter but there's no way to check that they are agree with each other so it's currently possible to have something like:

```
<Autocomplete.Root value={123} onChange={handleChange}>
    <Autocomplete.Input />
    <Autocomplete.Dropdown>
        <Autocomplete.Option value="Some string value">{option.label}</Autocomplete.Option>
    </Autocomplete.Dropdown>
</Autocomplete.Root>
```

which would yield horrible runtime errors.

Is there any way to make all these component use the same type parameter?

---

#### What have I tried

I was trying for example to only export a class `Autocomplete<T>` like this:

```
export class Autocomplete<T> {
    public Root = AutocompleteRoot<T>;
    public Input = AutocompleteInput<T>;
    public Dropdown = AutocompleteDropdown;
    public Option = AutocompleteOption<T>;
}
```

so that you can at least use:

```
type StringAutocomplete = Autocomplete<string>;
```

but React doesn't allow classes to be used that way in JSX.

Answer (score -1):

One approach you can take to ensure that all the components use the same type parameter is to use a generic interface for the props of each component.

Here's an example of how you can define the generic interface for each component:

```
interface AutocompleteRootProps<T> {
value: T;
onChange: (value: T) => void;
}

interface AutocompleteInputProps<T> {
  value: T;
  onChange: (value: T) => void;
}

interface AutocompleteDropdownProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

interface AutocompleteOptionProps<T> {
  value: T;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Then, you can define each component using the appropriate generic interface:

```
function AutocompleteRoot<T>(props: AutocompleteRootProps<T>) {
  // ...
}

function AutocompleteInput<T>(props: AutocompleteInputProps<T>) {
  // ...
}

function AutocompleteDropdown(props: AutocompleteDropdownProps) {
  // ...
}

function AutocompleteOption<T>(props: AutocompleteOptionProps<T>) {
  // ...
}
```

Finally, you can define the Autocomplete component as a higher-order component that takes the type parameter T and renders the other components with the correct props:

```
interface AutocompleteProps<T> {
  value: T;
  onChange: (value: T) => void;
  options: { value: T; label: string }[];
}

function Autocomplete<T>(props: AutocompleteProps<T>) {
  const { value, onChange, options } = props;

  return (
    <AutocompleteRoot value={value} onChange={onChange}>
      <AutocompleteInput value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      <AutocompleteDropdown>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <AutocompleteOption key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </AutocompleteOption>
        ))}
      </AutocompleteDropdown>
    </AutocompleteRoot>
  );
}
```

This approach ensures that all the components use the same type parameter T, and provides type safety when using the components. For example, if you try to use a value of the wrong type for the value prop of Autocomplete.Root, you'll get a TypeScript error at compile time instead of a runtime error.

Comment: That removes composition (being able to use multiple components).